# how can i hide a right navigation item of viewcontroller from a uiview class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation controller in a class, and i have a uiview class, now i need to hide the navigation item of view controller on click of a button in uiview class, because its a uiview class, am unable to access self.navigationcontroller.navigationitem,.

i tried initializing the viewcontroller like this

```
CustViewController* custListVC=[[CustViewController alloc]init];
custListVC.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
```

but this didnt help.

Comment: You need to provide more information, it is not quite understandable what exactly you want to achieve: _hide the navigation item of view controller on click of a button in uiview class_ ???? Are you using storyboards or are you doing everything programmatically? Then maybe it would make sense to share more code as well!

Comment: I have a master View controller (CustViewController), i have a navigation controller in app delegate which am using in every view controller. i have a detail view which is a subclass of UIVIEW(am adding it as subview to masterview). there is a button in detailView on tap of that button i need to hide the navigation item of MasterViewController

Answer (score 0):

you can use custListVC.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.hidden=YES;